# How to center TikZ automata?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I have the following code for an automaton, how can I put it on the page center (horizontally)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
 \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black]

 \node[initial,state]               (0)                     {$q_0$};
 \node[state,accepting]          (1)  [right of=0] {$q_1$};

 \path (0) edge  [loop above]  node {a} (0)
               edge [bend left]    node {b} (1)
         (1) edge  [loop above]   node {a} (1)
               edge [bend left]      node {b} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `\begin{center}/\end{center}` the figure is horizontally centered, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
 \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black]
 \node[initial,state]       (0)                     {$q_0$};
 \node[state,accepting]     (1)  [right of=0] {$q_1$};

 \path (0) edge  [loop above]  node {a} (0)
           edge [bend left]    node {b} (1)
       (1) edge  [loop above]  node {a} (1)
           edge [bend left]    node {b} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I added a frame around the tikz picture to make clear that the frame *is* centered. However, without the frame, the picture looks displaced because you probably expected the graph being centered without taking into account the "start" label. I.e., $b$ labels should be centered, right?

You can achieve this by telling tikz what part of the figure has to be considered part of the bounding box. This bounding box defines the width of the figure and everything outside of that bounding box will "overlap" the surroundings.

This is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,calc}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
 \path[use as bounding box] (0,-1) rectangle(3,1.5);
 \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black]
 \node[initial,state]       (0)               {$q_0$};
 \node[state,accepting]     (1)  [right of=0] {$q_1$};

 \path (0) edge [loop above]  node {a} (0)
           edge [bend left]   node {b} (1)
       (1) edge [loop above]  node {a} (1)
           edge [bend left]   node {b} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

This solution however is not satisfactory because the bounding box was defined in "absolute" coordinates, found by trial and error. A better solution would define the bounding box based on coordinates of nodes (0) and (1), but this is not possible until those nodes are drawn, and in this case this also (automatically) draws the "start" label, which is a problem because the bounding box should be defined before any content is drawn outside it.

Comment: shuld ir work the same with left and right?

Comment: @proton Sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean with left and right? A

Comment: left and right alignment

Comment: @proton Still not clear... Left alignment means "flush-left", I guess, so you only need to remove the `center` environment. But in this case, do you want to have the "start" label protruding the left margin? If not (which I think it is the most sensible option), no bounding box definition is required. Right alignment means flush-right, I guess. In this case remove `center` and put `\hfill` before `\begin{tikzpicture}`. For this case the bounding box is not required either, because there is no "protruding label" in the right part of the picture.

Answer (score 6):

I understand you want the diagram vertically centered:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\centering
~\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
 \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black]

 \node[initial,state]               (0)                     {$q_0$};
 \node[state,accepting]          (1)  [right of=0] {$q_1$};

 \path (0) edge  [loop above]  node {a} (0)
               edge [bend left]    node {b} (1)
         (1) edge  [loop above]   node {a} (1)
               edge [bend left]      node {b} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

Update:

If you just want horizontally centered, use `\centering` or `center`. Following code shows how `center` introduces some larger vertical space than `\centering`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

{\par\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
 \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black]

 \node[initial,state]               (0)                     {$q_0$};
 \node[state,accepting]          (1)  [right of=0] {$q_1$};

 \path (0) edge  [loop above]  node {a} (0)
               edge [bend left]    node {b} (1)
         (1) edge  [loop above]   node {a} (1)
               edge [bend left]      node {b} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\par}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
 \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black]

 \node[initial,state]               (0)                     {$q_0$};
 \node[state,accepting]          (1)  [right of=0] {$q_1$};

 \path (0) edge  [loop above]  node {a} (0)
               edge [bend left]    node {b} (1)
         (1) edge  [loop above]   node {a} (1)
               edge [bend left]      node {b} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it will not be the single content on the page, i meant horizontal centering.

Comment: @proton And what's the problem if you already use `\centering`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your problem is better shown if you put some text before and after your picture.

You can use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
ciao
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
 \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black]

 \node[initial,state]               (0)                     {$q_0$};
 \node[state,accepting]          (1)  [right of=0] {$q_1$};

 \path (0) edge  [loop above]  node {a} (0)
               edge [bend left]    node {b} (1)
         (1) edge  [loop above]   node {a} (1)
               edge [bend left]      node {b} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
ciao
\end{document}
```